# Not showing/creating custom headers on a listview, VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems to create custom headers in a listview on Excel VBA. Not sure if is the code or if is the system, Office16 x64. Thanks any help in advance.

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        .Gridlines = True    
    End With

        With .ColumnHeaders
            .Clear
            .Add , , "Item", 40
            .Add , , "Subitem-1", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-2", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-3", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-4", 55
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is an `End With` missing, you have 2 `With` statements so you need 2 `End With`. If you indent your code correcty you will immediately see it (I indented it for you).

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was the wrong position for the `End With` because your second `With .ColumnHeaders` starts with a dot it needs to be inside the first `With`. Move the first `End With` to the very end right after the second `End With`.

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        .Gridlines = True    

        With .ColumnHeaders
            .Clear
            .Add , , "Item", 40
            .Add , , "Subitem-1", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-2", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-3", 55
            .Add , , "Subitem-4", 55
        End With 'this ends With .ColumnHeaders

    End With 'this ends With ListView1
End Sub
```